# Calculate date ranges

Tags: sql

I am trying to calculate the items sold 90 days prior to 6/1/2009 and 90 days after 6/1/2009 with the query below. it shows some error. Would someone kindly edcuate me please???

```
SELECT
location,                       
SUM((CASE WHEN t.order_date DATEADD (DAY, -90, '6/1/2009') THEN t.Item ELSE NULL END) as Prior_Items,
SUM(CASE WHEN t.order_date DATEADD (DAY, 89,  '6/1/2009') THEN t.Item ELSE NULL END) as Post_Items
ELSE NULL
END)
FROM mytable t
where date = '6/1/2009'
group by location
```

Comment: *Some error* - "I did something to that thing and now the thingamajig is broken." Please be more specific, what error did you get?

Comment: @Chris: Care to share with us what the "some error" is?  It would save somebody trying to determine what the error is first before then having to determine the solution.

Comment: What kind of error is giving you? Did you miss the > and < in the case or it's just a copy error?

Comment: try something like: SELECT
location,                       
SUM(CASE WHEN t.order_date DATEADD (DAY, -90, '6/1/2009') THEN t.Item ELSE 0 END) as Prior_Items,
SUM(CASE WHEN t.order_date DATEADD (DAY, 89,  '6/1/2009') THEN t.Item ELSE 0 END) as Post_Items
FROM mytable t
where date = '6/1/2009'
group by location

Comment: A kind -1 towards your education in department of clear question writing (otherwise it's probably the parenthesis - your first sum's is closed only at the end and inside of it you are issuing column aliases, which suggests you intended to close it before)

Comment: did you get your problem solved? if not edit your question or add comments to clarify more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want something like this.

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME

SET @d = '20090106'


SELECT
location,                       
SUM(CASE WHEN t.order_date < @d and  t.order_date > DATEADD (DAY, -90, @d) THEN t.Item END) as Prior_Items,
SUM(CASE WHEN t.order_date >=@d AND  t.order_date <  DATEADD (DAY, 89,   @d) THEN t.Item END) as Post_Items
FROM mytable t
where t.order_date BETWEEN  DATEADD (DAY, -90, @d) AND DATEADD (DAY, 89,   @d)
group by location
```

Comment: Is `ELSE NULL` really needed ?  I believe `CASE` has default `ELSE NULL`

Answer (score 6):

your WHEN condition is not properly formed.

```
CASE WHEN t.order_date DATEADD (DAY, -90, '6/1/2009') THEN t.Item ELSE NULL END
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

most likely you want something like:

```
CASE WHEN t.order_date>=DATEADD (DAY, -90, '6/1/2009') THEN t.Item ELSE NULL END
                      ^^
```